# FIREBIRD How to search only the first word of a field?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to search only the first word of a field, ex:

My Table:

```
Name
---------------------
Henrique Melicio
José Eduardo da Silva
John McFly
```

My Query (results):

```
Name
-----------
Henrique
José
John
```

I need this query, but I do know to make SQL(Select?) statement. I tried using Substring, but I can't results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a split function before you pass in the query?

Comment: SELECT IIF(POSITION(‘ ‘ IN NOME_COMPLETO) > 0, SUBSTRING(NOME_COMPLETO FROM 1 FOR POSITION(‘ ‘ IN NOME_COMPLETO) – 1), NOME_COMPLETO) FROM TABLE

Answer (score 0):

May be you can take a look at [regular expression](http://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes25.html#rnfb25-dml-regex)

Comment: Please tailor this answer to statically provide insights that resolve the specific question asked.  This vague "hint" would otherwise be more suitable as a comment under the question.